# get_post_meta pagination

Tags: post-meta

I have custom field, array with multiple values

```
$metas = get_post_meta($post->ID, "$meta_key", false); 
foreach ( $metas as $metas ){
    echo $metas;    
}
```

Of course this will return an array.

How to paginate this? So for example:

```
www.example.com/post-title/1
```

will return `meta_value[0]`

and

```
www.example.com/post-title/2
```

will return `meta_value[1]`

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a singular view, the current page number can be accessed with `get_query_var('page')`. You need to subtract 1 to get the corresponding array value. Note that the first page will redirect to the URL without page number, this is just a thing WordPress does.

```
// get meta
$metas = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_meta_key', false );

// get page number
$page = get_query_var( 'page' );
$page = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 0;

// output meta for this page
if( isset( $metas[$page] ) ){
    echo $metas[$page];
}
```